# Saving data from single form into multiple tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Have a form that displays student information and the address.
My table structure is as follows:

```
Student
    ID - PK - AutoNumber
    Name    - Short Text
    Age     - Int

Address
    ID - PK - AutoNumber
    Student ID - FK - Number
    Door No - Int
    Address - Text
```

Student table has student id. Address table has a FK which is Student ID.
In my form I want the user to `enter the student name and address` information and this should be stored into multiple tables from this single form. ( I dont want to use sub form).

How can do the above? Do I need to write code in VBA and use unbound form?

Please provide inputs

Comment: tried creating the form using the form design and it puts a sub form. Another option I am trying is to have a save button and in the click handler do a sql insert of the student followed by sql insert of address.  Use Vba code or macros to do this. Looking for feasibility without writing vba code.

Comment: that's the point .. make some code based on that .. someone here can't help you when you have no code or achievement till you stuck ..

Comment: not asking for any code. Just wanted to validate the approach as to whether i need to write vba code or there is any inbuilt access functionality that can enable this. thanks

Comment: sorry .. your approach is right .. you just have to make it real .. cheers ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use VBA code or macros. Basically, you have to define the add,update and delete operations of the form. Define the "After Update" event, the "After Delete Confirm" and "After Insert" at the form level. Update your tables there. You might have to define other events depending on your needs.